# How to make a table with different object types in fyne-io?

Tags: go, user-interface, fyne

I use fyne-io to make an user interface. In a table, I want some cells with hyperlink and others with Label .

I try it but it doesn't work :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

func setDefaultColumnsWidth(table *widget.Table) {
    table.SetColumnWidth(0, 130)
    table.SetColumnWidth(1, 150)
    table.SetColumnWidth(2, 160)
    table.SetColumnWidth(3, 200)
    table.SetColumnWidth(4, 400)
    table.SetColumnWidth(5, 150)
    table.SetColumnWidth(6, 250)
    table.SetColumnWidth(7, 110)
    table.SetColumnWidth(8, 80)
}

func main() {

    application := app.New()
    win := application.NewWindow("Test GUI")

    data := [][]string{{"ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff"},
        {"ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff"},
        {"ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff", "ffffffffffffff"}}


    tableData := widget.NewTable(
        func() (int, int) {
            return len(data), len(data[0])
        },
        func() fyne.CanvasObject {
            label := widget.NewLabel("")
            return label
        },
        func(i widget.TableCellID, o fyne.CanvasObject) {
            switch o.(type) {
            case *widget.Label:
                label := o.(*widget.Label)
                label.SetText(data[i.Row][i.Col])

            case *widget.Hyperlink:
                fmt.Println("Found Hyperlink")
                hyperlink := o.(*widget.Hyperlink)


                //  hyperlink.SetText(data[i.Row][i.Col])
                hyperlink.SetText("aaaaaaa")
            }

        })
    setDefaultColumnsWidth(tableData)
    id := widget.TableCellID{Row: 1, Col: 1}
    hyperlink := widget.NewHyperlink("TUTU", nil)
    obj := fyne.CanvasObject(hyperlink)
    fmt.Println("UpdateCell...")
    tableData.UpdateCell(id, obj)

    label := widget.NewLabel("My table :")
    button := widget.NewButton("Close", func() {
        application.Quit()
    })

    container := layout.NewBorderLayout(label, button, nil, nil)
    box := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(container, label, tableData, button)
    win.SetContent(box)

    win.Resize(fyne.NewSize(1800, 400))
    win.ShowAndRun()
}
```

How can I do ?

I see message of "fmt.Println("Found Hyperlink")" but hyperlink isn't displayed.

Why o.(type) equals to *widget.Hyperlink and hyperlink isn't displayed ?

Comment: please check the answer and let know if needed any help or more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted the Fyne Slack group and a recommended solution is to encapsulate both elements in a container and display only the desired element at the update callback function

Create cell callback function :

```
func() fyne.CanvasObject {
    label := widget.NewLabelWithStyle("", fyne.TextAlignLeading, fyne.TextStyle{})
    hyperlink := widget.NewHyperlink("", nil)
    hyperlink.Hide()
    return container.NewMax(label, hyperlink)
}
```

Updade callback function :

```
func(i widget.TableCellID, o fyne.CanvasObject) {

    container := o.(*fyne.Container)
    label := container.Objects[0].(*widget.Label)
    hyperlink := container.Objects[1].(*widget.Hyperlink)

    switch i.Col {
    case 0:
    case 5:
        label.Hide()
        hyperlink.Hidden = false
        hyperlink.SetText("Hi!")
        hyperlink.SetURL(url.Parse("https://stackoverflow.com"))

    default:
        hyperlink.Hide()
        label.Hidden = false
        label.SetText("Hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seem the issue is that label does not get destroyed and overlaps newly created hyperlink. I am not able to find the solution for above problem but came up with alternative solution since [fyne](https://fyne.io/) API are in dev phase many internal functionalities are not accessible and may get changed the solution may changed overtime and get simplefied.

```golang
package main

import (
  "image/color"

  "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
  "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
  "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
  "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
  "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
)

const HEIGHT float32 = 30

func setDefaultColumnsWidth(table *widget.Table) {
  colWidths := []float32{130, 150, 160, 200, 400, 150, 250, 110, 80}
  for idx, colWidth := range colWidths {
    table.SetColumnWidth(idx, colWidth)
  }
}

func main() {

  application := app.New()
  win := application.NewWindow("Test GUI")

  data := [][]fyne.CanvasObject{
    {widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewHyperlink("TUTU", nil), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff")},
    {widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewHyperlink("ffffffffffffff", nil)},
    {widget.NewHyperlink("TUTU", nil), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff"), widget.NewLabel("ffffffffffffff")},
  }

  tableData := widget.NewTable(
    func() (int, int) {
      return len(data), len(data[0])
    },
    func() fyne.CanvasObject {
      c := fyne.NewContainerWithoutLayout()
      r := canvas.NewRectangle(color.White)
      r.SetMinSize(fyne.NewSize(0, HEIGHT))
      r.Resize(fyne.NewSize(0, HEIGHT))
      c.AddObject(r)
      return c
    },
    func(cell widget.TableCellID, o fyne.CanvasObject) {
      container := o.(*fyne.Container)
      var obj fyne.CanvasObject = data[cell.Row][cell.Col]
      container.AddObject(obj)
      container.Refresh()
  })

  setDefaultColumnsWidth(tableData)

  label := widget.NewLabel("My table :")
  button := widget.NewButton("Close", func() {
    application.Quit()
  })

  container := layout.NewBorderLayout(label, button, nil, nil)
  box := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(container, label, tableData, button)
  win.SetContent(box)

  win.Resize(fyne.NewSize(1800, 400))
  win.ShowAndRun()

}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: In this setup, links aren't clickable - if you try to embed button is off... so it's not very clean solution

Comment: @Slav links don't contain a valid url due to which they are not clickable however I did create example with `button` and it was working as expected

Answer (score 1):

There is a more complete writeup about how to use `container.NewMax` and `Table.SetColumnWidth` to create more complex tables. The example steps through the code for this table:

[image]

The two main tricks are to set up a container instead of a single widget:

```golang
container.NewMax(widget.NewLabel("template11"), widget.NewIcon(nil))
```

And then to hide or show items appropriately in the callback:

```golang
l := o.(*fyne.Container).Objects[0].(*widget.Label)
i := o.(*fyne.Container).Objects[1].(*widget.Icon)
l.Show()
i.Hide()
switch id.Col {
case 2:
    l.Hide()
    i.Show()
    i.SetResource(getIcon(id.Row))
case 0:
    l.SetText("hostname")
}
```

Read more at https://fynelabs.com/2022/12/30/building-complex-tables-with-fyne/